# .net framework 3.5 Error code: 0x800F081F

Tags: .net, windows-10

I have just updated my work PC to Windows 10 Enterprise. After the update I have noticed that all of my remote connection tools other than RDP wont install or wont work and I am getting a prompt to install .NET Framework 3.5. I have tried several different ways to install this feature but have had no success. I have visited quite a few online resources and tried most of their suggestions and still can't install. To this point I have:

1. Attempted to install using the Windows Update Installer on the PC itself and I get Error code: 0x800F081F
2. I have attempted to download the update via Microsoft and install without using the Windows Update with the same results
3. I have ran DISM repair through command prompt then tried to install with the same result
4. I have tried to turn on the .NET Framework 3.5 feature in the "Turn Windows Features On or Off" window of the PC

Plus multiple versions of the same items as above.

My question is am I missing something on the PC, is there another approach I can take, or is there something else broken I am just not seeing?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: This sounds like something you need to be contacting your IT department at work about.

Comment: Lol I am in the IT dept at my work. I just figured it out and will post an answer

Comment: Why the hell would someone downvote this? At least give a reason.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After quite a bit of looking I found the answer to my issue. Here is what fixed it. You must have a copy of the Windows 10 Setup Disk or an iso mounted with the setup files.

From an [Admin launch of command prompt](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2790-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-10-a.html) run:

```
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:F:\sources\sxs
```

Note: For the Windows 10 Installer on USB Stick, use:

`Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:F:\x64\sources\sxs`

Where `F:` is the drive letter where the setup disk or virtual disk with the Windows 10 setup files are located. The command prompt will run through a repair and activation of the .net framework feature.